# Метод execute VK API некорректно работает

Tags: javascript, php, vkontakte-api, vkscript

Есть VK Script код, который полностью работает и отлажен через сайт VK API. Сейчас он в коде, ужасно, да, но это временно. Для отладки мне тупо нужно отправить уже готовый, а не сгенерированный код. В ответ приходит: [image: Ответ вк апи]

Еще раз повторюсь, этот же самый код правильно работает, если запустить его через их сайт.

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<?php
$token = "6b56c4297eaedfdgdfggf4a3c9abf70fb6b2f13e5af4cbed8167a3274f9b447688725b642a8fc8c184";
$secret = "d6a4cfdgfgdfgb69852";
//$codeToApi = file_get_contents("js/VKTESTRESULT.txt");
$codeToApi = "
var getGroupOriginalId = API.groups.getById({\"group_id\" : \"licey_pri_ulgtu\"});
var realGroupId = getGroupOriginalId@.id;
var getSearchResultFromGroupMembers = API.users.search({\"group_id\" : realGroupId, \"sex\" : 1,\"sort\" : 0, \"offset\" : 0, \"count\" : 30, \"age_from\" : 15, \"age_to\" : 18, \"has_photo\" : 1, \"fields\" : \"photo_200_orig, sex, online, bdate, city, status\"});
var i = 0;
var resultAnswer = {};
while(i != 10) {
    var id = getSearchResultFromGroupMembers.items[i].id;
    var firstName = getSearchResultFromGroupMembers.items[i].first_name;
    var lastName = getSearchResultFromGroupMembers.items[i].last_name;
    var bDate = getSearchResultFromGroupMembers.items[i].bdate;
    var city = getSearchResultFromGroupMembers.items[i].city;
    var sex = getSearchResultFromGroupMembers.items[i].sex;
    var online = getSearchResultFromGroupMembers.items[i].online;
    var status = getSearchResultFromGroupMembers.items[i].status;
    var photo_200_orig = getSearchResultFromGroupMembers.items[i].photo_200_orig;
    
    var getGroupMemberPhotos = API.photos.getAll({\"owner_id\" : id, \"count\" : 5, \"skip_hidden\" : 1});
    var photo1 = getGroupMemberPhotos.items[1];
    var photo2 = getGroupMemberPhotos.items[2];
    var photo3 = getGroupMemberPhotos.items[3];
    var photo4 = getGroupMemberPhotos.items[4];
    
    resultAnswer.push({\"id\" : id, \"firstName\" : firstName, \"lastName\" : lastName, \"bDate\" : bDate, \"city\" : city, \"sex\" : sex, \"online\" : online, \"status\" : status, \"photo_200_orig\" : photo_200_orig, \"photo1\" : photo1, \"photo2\" : photo2, \"photo3\" : photo3, \"photo4\" : photo4});
    
    i = i+1;
}
return resultAnswer;
";

$requestParams = [
    'access_token' => $token,
    'code' => $codeToApi
];


$sig = "/method/execute?" . http_build_query($requestParams) . $secret;
$sig = md5($sig);

$getGroupMembersInfo = "https://api.vk.com/method/execute?" . http_build_query($requestParams) . "&sig={$sig}";
$groupMembersInfo = file_get_contents($getGroupMembersInfo);

echo $groupMembersInfo;
```

Токен я изменил, так что пытаться что-то сделать бестолку)

Comment: По умолчанию сейчас стоит старая версия (3.0)...Поставьте в `requestParams` версию, `'v'=>5.37`  (это последняя) - должно работать.... На будущее: стоит всегда указывать версию апи